# Downloading files hangs up in Cypress

Tags: testing, cypress

I've got the issue that after clicking the 'Download' button in Cypress the file actually gets downloaded, but the test hangs up. I honestly googled and found it has been raised a lot, but as both file uploading and downloading are not supported by Cypress directly (only with some workarounds), there are some solutions offered, but none works for me. The files URL is impossible to figure out first of all because it's dynamic, and each time I upload the same file it gets the new name with an auto-generated time-stamp. moreover, I need to test downloading several (or many) selected files at once. I found many solutions proposed (e.g. [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/949)), but all require the target URL. Is there any other way to test downloading?

```
 it('Adds and downloads documents', function () {
    cy.get('[type="checkbox"]#documents-list-select-all').check({ force: true }); //select all button, as you can guess from the name
    cy.get('#documents-list-selected-actions').click(); //this is the actual download button
    cy.waitLoadingOverlay();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer as of June 2020: at the moment there's no way to test non `text/html` content-type pages.
The topic is discussed here:
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1551

The only thing you can do is adding to your code that if it is executed in cypress, it should skip download, i.e. you press the button but cypress does nothing, only clicks the button. Of course this test would only test that the button is active, not the actual download, but in case you need it...